# numpy.exceptions.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1 (ROC_AUC)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get the ROC_AUC results from the below code!

```
import itertools
import os

import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, roc_auc_score

# model
model = Sequential()

# first conv layer
# input shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 1)
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(100, 120, 1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# second conv layer
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

# flatten and put a fully connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))  # fully connected
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# softmax layer
model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))

# model summary
optimiser = Adam()
model.compile(optimizer=optimiser, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.summary()

# Loading the Dataset

DATASET_PATH = 'D:\\Memoire\\Model_Training\\HandFinal\\data.old\\'

dataset_path = os.path.join(DATASET_PATH, '*')
import glob

dataset_path = glob.glob(dataset_path)
dataset_path

import cv2

image = cv2.imread('D:\\Memoire\\Model_Training\\HandFinal\\data.old\\five\\hand1(1015).jpg')
image = cv2.resize(image, (100, 120))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))

loaded_images = []

list_of_gestures = ['blank', 'ok', 'thumbsup', 'thumbs-down', 'fist', 'five']

for path in range(0, len(dataset_path)):
    dataset_path = "D:\\Memoire\\Model_Training\\HandFinal\\data.old\\" + str(list_of_gestures[path])
    print(dataset_path)
    gesture_path = os.path.join(dataset_path, '*')
    import glob

    gest_path = glob.glob(gesture_path)
    k = 0
    for i in range(0, len(gest_path)):
        if k < 1600:
            image = cv2.imread(gest_path[i])
            gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            gray_image = cv2.resize(gray_image, (100, 120))
            loaded_images.append(gray_image)
        k = k + 1
print(len(loaded_images))

outputVectors = []
for i in range(1, 1334):
    outputVectors.append([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

for i in range(1, 1334):
    outputVectors.append([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])

for i in range(1, 1334):
    outputVectors.append([0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])

for i in range(1, 1334):
    outputVectors.append([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

for i in range(1, 1335):
    outputVectors.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])

for i in range(1, 1335):
    outputVectors.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])

print("len(outputVectors)", len(outputVectors))

X = np.asarray(loaded_images)
y = np.asarray(outputVectors)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=4)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 100, 120, 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 100, 120, 1)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

# Training the model with data
model.fit(X_train, y_train,
          batch_size=128,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(X_test, y_test))

model.save("D:\\Memoire\\Model_Training\\HandFinal\\hand_gesture_recognition.h5")



[loss, acc] = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: " + str(acc))

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_test = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
# plt.show()
print(cm)
# Create a Confusion Matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred))

# Compute the ROC AUC score
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, multi_class='ovr')
print('ROC AUC Score :', roc_auc)
```

however i got the below error code !! can you please help !

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Memoire\Model_Training\HandFinal\TrainingModel.py", line 138, in <module>
    roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred, multi_class='ovr')
  File "C:\Users\Haythem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_param_validation.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Haythem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 621, in roc_auc_score
    return _multiclass_roc_auc_score(
  File "C:\Users\Haythem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py", line 693, in _multiclass_roc_auc_score
    if not np.allclose(1, y_score.sum(axis=1)):
  File "C:\Users\Haythem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 49, in _sum
    return umr_sum(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims, initial, where)
numpy.exceptions.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```